# Failure of starting a Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I created a new empty project via Spring boot initializr and when I run it Im getting this exception about failed to write metadata in spring.components.file and fail to start. Anybody has an idea how to solve it?

```
java: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to write metadata
Attempt to reopen a file for path /home/lenovo/Downloads/spring-crm-rest-demo/demo/target/classes/META-INF/spring.components
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please check if you have write permission to spring.components

Comment: Since `C:/` drive has lots of permission issues, move the `spring-crm-rest-demo` directory to another drive and then try running.

Comment: Its on linux and i check all accesses and all of them on read and write.